# 405 (Not Allowed) on POST request

Tags: nginx, php

Everything worked before problems with Winginx occurred. When I send data with Jquery with POST method I get 405 (Not Allowed) error. GET works perfectly fine.

When I request data from /formcheck (which is forcmcheck.php and works fine on its own) I get this error. I ain't changed anything in Nginx logs except few lines for rewrite engine.

You can see logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2017:15:14:06 +0300] "POST /formcheck HTTP/1.1" 405 575 "http://music-portfolio.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2017:15:16:35 +0300] "POST /formcheck HTTP/1.1" 405 575 "http://music-portfolio.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2017:15:17:32 +0300] "POST /formcheck HTTP/1.1" 405 575 "http://music-portfolio.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Here is everything okay, except any data was transferred.

I don't know how or where POST can be blocked, but I need it to be allowed...

Comment: Looks like this is a popular question now. I don't really know what actually happened back there but after some weird magic with winginx it actually worked. But anyway I deleted it instantly after like 3 problems of this type and now I use openserver/xampp/vagrant. The first one is pretty easy to use and does everything automatically on windows. I would be really happy if this helps someone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually these error messages are caused by the limitation that **Nginx can't serve static content on `POST` request**. This issue is discussed and workarounds suggested on InValidLogic.com's article [Serving Static Content Via POST From Nginx](http://invalidlogic.com/2011/04/12/serving-static-content-via-post-from-nginx/): in that case you could replace the error message with `error_page 405 =200 $uri;` or create a proxy for static content, converting `POST` request to `GET`.

However, in this case your `/formcheck` is actually a PHP script instead of static content, thus `POST` requests should be allowed by Nginx and there is `POST` data to be received, so converting to `GET` isn't an option, either.

It seems you have two `location` sections:

```
    location / {
        if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
            root home/$2/public_html;
            access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
            root home/$2/public_html;
            access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
        }
        if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9071;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

As you can see, only locations ending with `.php` are handled with fastcgi, while everything else including `/formcheck` falls into `location /` serving only static content, causing the `405` error.

Comment: So... To fix this I should return to formcheck.php or put it in another directory with only .php files to apply the new rule to them all?

Comment: ...or add a new matching `location`. :)

Comment: The only problem is that there will be more files like this, so to make them all work I will need to define every single one in location? Or can you bring some basic example of location for this?